# VeraCode-Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS) (CWE ID 80)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, veracode

VeraCode has been give the High Priority Issue for the following code at the try block closing braces.

```
    public string GenerateExcelFilePath(string strFileName)
    {

        string strExcelFileFullFilePath = string.Empty;
        string strFolderName = string.Empty;
        ExcelGeneration objExcelFile = null;
        UserImpersonation objUserImpersonation = null;
        try
        {
            strFolderName = "Excel Files";
            objExcelFile = new ExcelGeneration();
            objUserImpersonation = new UserImpersonation();
            objUserImpersonation.impersonateUser(DACommon.Shared_UserName, DACommon.Shared_Domain, DACommon.Shared_Password);

            // Use Path.Combine
            strExcelFileFullFilePath = objExcelFile.GetExcelFilePath(strFileName, strFolderName);
            strExcelFileFullFilePath = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(strExcelFileFullFilePath, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

            // IF file exists,delete the file
            objExcelFile.CheckIsFileExists(strExcelFileFullFilePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        return strExcelFileFullFilePath;

    }
```

Comment: What on Earth??

Comment: what happened.?